# Move all objects in a collection with a proximity node in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is there a way to use geometry node to move all objects in a collection and move all single objects with another geometry with proximity node?

I'm stuck in try to get the single object from collection info node.

I know that I can do it with animation node, but I'd like to know if there is a way with geometry node also.

Comment: i don't think you can do that with GN. But should be possible via python.

Comment: The problem is that GN does not manipulate object data. So use Animation nodes.

Comment: Yes, that should work by wrapping everything in a single node tree. Would that be an option for you?

Comment: Could you please show us your plan with a more detailed example? Screenshot, or the actual node tree, so we have a clue what exactly your goal is? Thank you!